# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cos(\theta n)}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to deduce convergence of this series for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Clearly absolute convergence won't work here as that behaves like the harmonic series.

I tried to apply Leibniz' criterion, for which I have to show that the sequence of terms without the alternating factor is decreasing, but this didn't work out. I tried to prove this using derivatives.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the real part of the series $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{e^{n \rho}}{n+1}$ with $\rho = \pi + \theta$. By [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) the series converges whenever $\rho$ is not a multiple of $2 \pi$, i.e. for all $\theta$ except odd multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use summation by parts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

This would transform the problem of convergence of your series into the convergence of the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{\sin(n \theta)}{(n+1)^2}$, 
which is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I did not do any details, but I think doing summation by parts is the proper way to do it. In the same way, integration by parts is the easiest way to show that the integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)/x$ converges.

Comment: What do you mean with transform? Could you please add more details?